# Server in Amazon Cloud not coming up after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a server hosted in Amazon cloud which I'm accessing it remotely over ssh. I'm not aware of much details about the server setup. I had been given the IP and credentials to access it remotely.

Now, I have tried to reboot(sudo reboot) the server from the remote console. But after the reboot command, server is not coming up. I'm not able to access the server using the same IP & credentials. Could you please help me find what has gone wrong here? Does the server change its IP when we reboot ?

Thanks in advance.

-Dilip

Comment: You will need access to the aws console to find out what happened to the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is not assigned an Elastic IP, the hostname changes upon every reboot.

Log into AWS console, find your instance and determine if the instance is assigned a hostname, or if it is assigned an elastic IP. Make sure you are using the correct information to log in.

Also, depending upon the shutdown behavior, the instance may be terminated on stop. If you log in and find your instance terminated I would suggest enabling termination protection to prevent this from occurring again.

If you are unable to log into the AWS console, I suggest contacting the server admin for further assistance.

Comment: That is not entirely true, if its strictly a reboot, it will keep its ip. It will not on stop/start however.

Comment: Thanks Robert and Datasage for prompt your responses.
I will try logging into AWS console and update the outcome.